# Playing music in a call with Twilio

Tags: twilio, twilio-twiml

How can you play music in a call with (preferably) a TwiML XML file? I have gotten so far as:

```
<!-- page located at http://example.com/simple_dial.xml -->
<Response>
<Dial>PHONE NUMBER</Dial>
<Play>
AUDIO FILE URL
</Play>
</Response>
```

but it waits until PHONE NUMBER hangs up to play the audio. How can I call a phone number, and then play an mp3 in the call?

Answer (score 2):

[Initiate a new call via the REST API](http://www.twilio.com/docs/api/rest/making-calls), using a URL that returns the following TwiML:

```
<Response>
    <Play>AUDIO FILE URL</Play>
</Response>
```

[Here's a quickstart tutorial](http://www.twilio.com/docs/quickstart/php/rest/call-request) that talks through the process of making an outbound call with the PHP helper library. It's equally easy with the libraries in the other languages as well.

Comment: The Linked Quickstart also allows you to choose from .NET/C#, Ruby, and Python as languages that the examples are written in.

Comment: I'm confused. The original question was very specific, but you point to a documentation page that doesn't address the specific question. How do I play music on hold WHILE twilio attempts to connect my call?