# twilio API: how can I play an audio file to both sides of a voice call and not disconnect the call?

Tags: ios, twilio, twilio-twiml

Twilio API: how can I play an audio file to both sides of a voice call and not disconnect the call?

I have a working iOs client which makes a call to a destination number. but I would like to play an audio file so that both callers and callee hear the audio file playing, and then resume the conversation. I doesn't matter if the parties can hear each other while the audio file is playing.

I have read 
[Playing music in a call with Twilio](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8981000/playing-music-in-a-call-with-twilio)
and
[How to say/play something to everyone in a call in Twilio](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18532787/how-to-say-play-something-to-everyone-in-a-call-in-twilio)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Twilio evangelist here.

Using `<Conference>` could be a good solution for you in this scenario.  What you would do is dial both of your callers into a conference.  Then you have Twilio dial a third call into that conference and have that call `<Play>` the audio into conference.

Hope that helps.